# Why are these checkbox values reversed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of checkboxes.  When the page is loaded, some a checked, others are not.  When the user clicks on the checkbox I have a jQuery function that checks whether the chosen checkbox is checked or not.

The problem is that I am getting positive results when the checkbox is not checked, and vice versa.  Here's an example of the HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="update-member">
<input type="checkbox" class="update-member" checked>
```

Here is the javascript:

```
updateMembership : function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
        console.log('Checked!');
    } else {
        console.log('NOT Checked');
    }
}
```

For example, when the user clicks the first checkbox, it says 'Checked!' in the console.

Perhaps it's my thinking that's reversed?  Not the javascript?

Comment: When `updateMembership` is called ? Use `change` listener instead of `click` listener..

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/7co3rumo/1/

Comment: As an aside, `this.checked` is more efficient to type *and* to execute than `$(this).prop('checked')`. @Rayon - `click` event works fine if you don't prevent the default behaviour.

Comment: @nnnnnn — You are right! But I would not use it in such use-case, would you ? :)

Comment: @Rayon - Actually I *would* use click rather than change for checkboxes, a leftover habit from the old days when certain browsers didn't trigger the checkbox change event until the control lost focus. (Noting that click is triggered even if the checkbox is changed via the keyboard.)

Comment: @nnnnnn — Yeah, usability..

Comment: I don't really want to use the change listener, since I am planning to make an ajax call after the checkbox is checked, and update the UI based on the response.

Comment: @KimPrince changed events from `change` to `click` and results unchanged. It still functions successfully, review answer at your convenience.

Comment: @KimPrince  If you are making an ajax call *after a checkbox is checked* or *after a checkbox is clicked*? The former implies that a checkbox needs have a checkmark in the checkbox, the latter implies the checkbox needs to be clicked whether it ends up checked or not. Either way, the results are the same since you have if and else, I don't think it matters whether it's `click` or `change`. Each event results in a change of the checkboxes' states regardless.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is a bit speculative, but one explanation for your observations is that the checkboxes are actually being rendered out of the order which you think was being used.  Your observations would actually make sense if the checkbox with the `checked` property appeared on the left (first), and the one without any property appeared on the right.

If you show us your CSS, we may be able to confirm this by looking more closely at the layout.

Answer (score 0):

I think when you use:

> ```
> if ($(this).prop('checked'))
> ```

...it always returns `true` because it's reporting itself as an existing property and not whether it is actively checked or not.

The Snippet uses this conditional:

> ```
> if ($(this).is(':checked'))
> ```

...it returns a boolean that reflects the checkbox's state of being `:checked`.
Not really sure what use `e.preventDefault()` would be using checkboxes, so I removed it.

**SNIPPET**

```js
$('.update-member').on('click', updateMembership);


function updateMembership(e) {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    console.log('Checked!');
  } else {
    console.log('NOT Checked');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="update-member">
<input type="checkbox" class="update-member" checked>
```